# Swift Only execute code if Location Services are enabled

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocation, uirefreshcontrol

Need some help on only executing code if my location services are enabled because I have a tableview that takes data from firebase and organizes it by distance and do not want the app to crash for users. I also have a UIRefreshControl that I only want to execute code if the location services are enabled as well. My current set up doesn't do what I am looking for. I am posting my whole ViewDidLoad as well as my UIRefreshControl. getTableViewData() is the code I want executed based on if the location services are enabled. Thanks.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()


    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
        case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
            print("No access")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Access")
            getTableViewData()
        }
    } else {
        print("Location services are not enabled")
    }

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RegisteredLocations.handleRefresh(refreshControl:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refresher)
}


@objc func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    self.usersArray.removeAll()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
        case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
            print("No access")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Access")
            getTableViewData()
        }
    } else {
        print("Location services are not enabled")
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: what happens? what is not working?

Comment: It doesn't execute "getTableViewData()" when I allow access.

Comment: I don't want "getTableViewData()" to execute if the access was denied.

Comment: If I denied access to location and I do "UIRefreshControl" by pulling down the tableview, it throws an error which would crash the app for users

Answer (score 0):

You should check the return value of this method before starting location updates to determine whether the user has location services enabled for the current device. Location services prompts users the first time they attempt to use location-related information in an app but does not prompt for subsequent attempts. If the user denies the use of location services and you attempt to start location updates anyway, the location manager reports an error to its delegate.

The work around is to present an alert to open the app settings for the user to enable the location service.

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Please Allow the location Service to open this screen.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)! as URL)
    }))

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```